# Why am I getting leading and trailing backslash when I replace my placeholder in Python?

Tags: python, sql

I have this sample query string:

```
    """SELECT security_id   AS securityID,
       trade_date    AS date,
       available,
       currency_code AS sourceCurrency
    FROM   cppib_market_passive_swap_availability
    WHERE  trade_date = '{file_date}' """.format(file_date=passive_availablity_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

When the code runs with passive_availablity_date having a datetime value '2022-11-29 00:00:00' the string that gets formed is:

```
SELECT security_id   AS securityID,
       trade_date    AS date,
       available,
       currency_code AS sourceCurrency
    FROM   cppib_market_passive_swap_availability
    WHERE  trade_date = \'2022-11-29\'
```

I dont want to get the backslashes in the date it should be just **trade_date = '2022-11-29'** .
I have another similar string but there it works fine. I am not able to understand what is happening here. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

The backslashes you see around the datetime (`\'`) are likely just artifacts to remind you that they are literal single quotes, perhaps inside of a singly quoted string.

As a side note, it is generally bad practice to be injecting a value into a SQL query this way.  Instead, you should learn how to use a prepared statement.

Comment: not sure how to use prepared statements here. I am using this to query AWS Athena.  On a side note the same thing runs fine when I run in a scratch file but here I am getting \ and because of it the query fails to run in Athena